# Sending parameters in Jquery Ajax call with quotes, double or single

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am unable to send data through my ajax call if the user put quotes in the textarea. Is there a way to send text with quotes? I dont want to get rid of the quotes. I guess this is usually not a big problem, i found very little online about this situation.

```
var description = $('#Description').val();
var title = $('#Title').val();
var parameters = '{content:' + $('#ContentCheck').is(':checked') +
                        ',title: "' + title + '",desciption:"' + description + '"}';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout `JSON.stringify(object)` which is built into javascript.

The jist is, you create a javascript object, and call stringify to create a JSON string.  With your information given above, you might do:

```
var jsonText = JSON.stringify({
    'content': $('$('#ContentCheck').is(':checked'),
    'title':   title,
    'description': description
});
```

Here we define a javascript hash using the curly braces, and then pass it to stringify.

Comment: Probably easier to process as an array, rather than a string... though this might require some changes in the backend...

Answer (score 2):

same problem was with me.I tried this and completely working

```
 xmlhttp.open("POST","test_test.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.send("name="+encodeURIComponent(name)+"&details="+encodeURIComponent(details)+"&r_price="+r_price+"&o_price="+o_price+"&id="+id);
```

and use urldecode($_REQUEST['details'])` when inserting.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert parameters into a map -- basically an associative array -- instead of a string. That way, you can do string manipulation in the backend .NET without any changes in your frontend js; e.g.

```
var url = 'http://path/to/your/backend/script';
var parameters = {
    contentCheck: $('#ContentCheck').is(':checked'),
    title: title,
    description: description
};
$.post(url, parameters);
```

Comment: can you give me an example of what the server side would look like, I am still getting errors using my 3 parameters. Thanks.

Comment: Well, my reply is a bit late. FYI, JSON.Stringify() is new, so I still prefer to pass parameters as a map. The server-side implementation entirely depends on what language you use; e.g. for PHP, I would use json_decode() to get retrieve my parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode quotes using js and decode it server side to get the original string

//js

```
function totalEncode(s){
str= s.replace(/\&/g,'&amp;');
str= str.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
str= str.replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
str= str.replace(/\"/g,'&quot;');
str= str.replace(/\'/g,'&#039;');
return(str);
}
```